# Should I use docker in order to be able to run ChomeDriver on Azure Web App Services in Django Server?

Tags: django, azure, docker

Recently I have started a Django server on Azure Web App Service, now I want to add a usage of "ChromoDriver" for web scraping, I have noticed that for that I need to install some additional Linux packages (not python) on the machine. the problem is that it gets erased on every deployment, does it mean that I should switch to Docker ?

Answer (score 0):

Container works, but you can also try to pull down the additional packages in the custom start up file without messing around the machine after the deployment

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-04